# count of collect_list in hive and display the count as per the condition

Tags: hive, hiveql

I would like to have a count of collect_list in hive and depending on the count of all_measure_desc display the count and values like

0-1 low

2-3 medium

3-5 high

< 5 catastrophic

Below is my query in hive

```
SELECT 
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk,
    COLLECT_LIST(t3.measure_title) as all_measure_desc
FROM qms_gic_lifecycle t1 
INNER JOIN dim_member t2 
on t1.member_id = t2.member_id
INNER JOIN dim_quality_measure t3 
on t1.quality_measure_id = t3.quality_measure_id
GROUP BY  
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk;
```

Comment: I was able to get the count  using size as below any idea how to display the mapping values like low,medium,high etc accordingly.SELECT 
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk,
    COLLECT_LIST(t3.measure_title) as all_measure_desc,
    size( COLLECT_LIST(t3.measure_title)) as ps
FROM qms_gic_lifecycle t1 
INNER JOIN dim_member t2 
on t1.member_id = t2.member_id
INNER JOIN dim_quality_measure t3 
on t1.quality_measure_id = t3.quality_measure_id
where t1.status <> 'closed'
GROUP BY  
    t1.member_id,
    t2.first_name,
    t2.date_of_birth_sk;

Answer (score 0):

Using case:

```
case when size <= 1 then 'low' 
     when size in (2,3) then 'medium'
     when size in (4,5) then 'high'
     when size >5 then 'catastrophic' 
end as display_value
```